# Java Serialization with RMI

Tags: serialization, rmi

I'm working on a project using Java RMI. 
This is the class causing problem:

```
public class FSFile implements Serializable 
{
public static final int READ    = 0;
public static final int WRITE   = 1;

private int     flag;
private String  filename;

private transient BufferedWriter  writer;
private transient BufferedReader  reader;

...

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
    stream.writeObject(writer);
    stream.writeObject(reader);    
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    stream.defaultReadObject();
    writer      = (BufferedWriter) stream.readObject();
    reader      = (BufferedReader) stream.readObject();
}
}
```

Basically, I use RMI to send that FSFile object to another process locally (for now) and here's the error I get:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:                                                                      
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException;
java.io.BufferedReader
```

To be more precise, there's one class named FileService which use a function fetch() from a FileServer to get a FSFile in return. There is nothing special in the fetch() function, it just creates a FSFile and returns it. All communications between those classes are made via RMI.

How come I have an error like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize readers and writers. It makes no sense. It's like trying to send a telephone over a telephone line. If you want to send a file, send the file.

And your code just calls writeObject on these objects as though they were Serializable. They aren't. Otherwise you could have made them non-transient and omitted the custom readObject and writeObject methods altogether. Just re-coding what the system would have done anyway doesn't change anything. It certainly doesn't make classes Serializable that aren't.

Comment: So you're suggesting me to send a File instead of my custom class ?
What I wanted to do is from one end, just with that FSFile call a read or write which will be performed locally on the other end. What I wanted to do with the writeObject and readObject is just to keep the state of it.

Comment: The fact is that the remote user can't write nor read with the class File.

Comment: No I'm not suggesting to send a File. That's just a name. I'm talking about sending the content. If you want to implement some kind of remote file with I/O capabilities that's another story, you have to implement your own RemoteOutputStream etc. Not trivial, not impossible, not a great way to design a system IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to re-implement file/stream sending via RMI you could look into [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio), it handles such things in concise and effective way.