# How to share an InputStream or an OutputStream while using RMI?

Tags: java, inputstream, rmi, outputstream

I have a server side application to which I'm attempting to share access to via RMI.  The application has an abstract representation of an "item" which is most commonly represents a file but could represent almost any arbitrary data including stream (streaming radio, streaming data from a sensor).  Consequently any "item" is accessed through an InputStream (alongside a method to indicate the file size if it can be known).

While RMI is sufficient for the rest of the application, it really can't handle InputStreams.

It strikes me that the need to access InputStreams while using RMI must be a common problem. So I was wondering:
What are the recommended solutions?

*Note I need the client to both send and receive input streams and serializing to a byte array is not viable because some of them actually do represent a stream of data, not just a file.*

Comment: You may be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356665/java-serialization-with-rmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio) library to share streams over RMI.

See classes: `com.healthmarketscience.rmiio.RemoteInputStream` and `com.healthmarketscience.rmiio.RemoteOutputStream`

See also: [Remote streaming reference with RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/class_reference.html#Remote_Streaming)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing streams, can you pass a sort of 'stream handle'? That is, an object which is not a stream itself, but can produce a stream on demand. Something like:

```
public interface StreamHandle extends Serializable {
    public InputStream getStream();
}

public class WebStreamHandle implements StreamHandle {
    private URL url;
    public InputStream getStream() {
        return url.openStream();
    }
}

public class SocketStreamHandle implements StreamHandle {
    private String host;
    private int port;
    public InputStream getStream() {
        return new Socket(host, port).getInputStream();
    }
}

public class BufferStreamHandle implements StreamHandle {
    private byte[] buffer;
    public InputStream getStream() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    }
}
```

The key thing would be to ensure that the code was able to produce a stream independently of the machine it was executed on. So, you couldn't refer to a file (unless it was file you knew would be on every machine, or was a UNC path), but you can refer to resources on the network.

Then, you could pass the handles around, and produce the streams on demand.

Comment: This will work as long as the server has a web server attached/incorporated to provide access to the URL.  I didn't state this in the question but the server must always act as a proxy, the client must never fetch the data for itself.

Comment: Aha. I was thinking this was a case where your apps were discussing streams that originated somewhere off in the distance (eg from remote sensors or radio stations), in which case it wouldn't matter which machine retrieved them. If that's not the case, then this approach doesn't help much, and DRCB's answer is a much better one.

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed a lightweight solution [Serializable InputStream](https://github.com/dajudge/serializable-input-stream) to Github for passing an `InputStream` over RMI that is conceptually very similar to [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio). This might solve your problem. With that library you can easily wrap your `InputStream` to make it serializable:

```
serializableStream = new SerializableInputStream(originalInputStream);
```

Basically it leverages the behavior of `ObjectOutputStream` to call [special methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) (if present) on classes that implement `Serializable`:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

Using these methods, the `SerializableInputStream` forwards chunks read from the delegate `InputStream` into the processing `ObjectOutputStream` used  by the RMI framework. These chunks then get deserialized on the other end (either into an in-memory cache or into a temp file - that's configurable and depends on your needs).

As for your requirement that...

> "some of them actually do represent a stream of data, not just a file"

...I  believe that either you need to further clarify your needs or reconsider if RMI is really the technique that suits your use case: I cannot see how sending (potentially never-ending) streams of data over a method-invocation-based interface could work out for you.

Comment: curious what your motivation was for creating this library?  is there a feature missing from rmiio which your library adds?